# shortcuts, pinned to taskbar, seem to loose some menu content

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, taskbar, onedrive

I'm working with a Windows-10 computer, and it's already several months that I have Google Chrome pinned to my taskbar. The corresponding menu looks as follows:

```
Recently closed:
   ...
Tasks:
   New Window
   New Incognito Window
Google Chrome
Unpin from taskbar
```

Recently only the last items remain:

```
Google Chrome
Unpin from taskbar
```

In order to get the complete menu back, I need to unpin from taskbar, pin again, and then it works again, mostly until I open an incognito window again.

Does anybody know what's causing this? Does anybody know where the menu items of a pinned taskbar icon are stored?

Comment: If you close the incognito window and have a normal window back, does it show the item again? If not, you may want to try the following: unpin, reboot, pin. If that doesn't work, see if there's an update for Chrome and install it. It may just be a bug.

Comment: @LPChip: thanks for your proposal, but after some retries it seems still not to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very weird, but it seems to be a side-effect of OneDrive: this program has recently been installed (automatically) on my PC. I've removed it from the startup folder (it's still installed, but not started up anymore), and now I don't have the issue with my Google Chrome shortcuts anymore.